# What is gained by modifying a variable in place vs reassignment in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, immutability

In ruby, an array might be updated in one of the following ways:

```rb
original_array = []
original_array << 'first'

# or

original_array = []
original_array = original_array + ['first']
```

Are there advantages in the second form? I am asking as it "feels" immutable, but knowing the variable is simply reassigned has me thinking it offers nothing but a longer statement and uses a little more memory.

At the same time, experiences with immutability in other langues produces a negative reaction in me to `array << 'something'`.

Are there significant advantages to mutating a variable (array, hash, etc) in place in Ruby? Are there advantages to reassigning the same variable from an "immutable" operation? Is "immutability" even an appropriate concept with which to describe this?

Comment: You need to avoid #1 if, after mutating `original_array`, you need the original `original_array` for something else. It's as simple as that. Advocates of the [functional programming](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-functional-programming-7f218c68b3a0) style avoid mutating objects, period.

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland - and I think were in agreement. I posted this question as naively as I could, as Im trying to uncover if the functional style has any merit in this specific case for Ruby. Today Im wondering if I am just preferring a "functional style" that isnt gaining the benefits and just eating more memory cuz its Ruby and not a pure functional language.

Comment: Notice that difference of memory consumption is so very very very tiny, that you can ignore it for sake of readability of the written code. Which option is more readable is a decision which you or your team should make.

Comment: The `<<` example **modifies the object** and leaves the variable unchanged. The `=` example **modifies the variable** and leaves the (original) object unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

The in-place version, `x << y`, is more memory efficient as the existing object is extended. This reduces pressure on the garbage collector.

The alternate, with either `x = x + [ y ]` or `x += [ y ]` is far less efficient, where you're creating an extremely short-lived temporary array, then appending that to a new array, then discarding the old array.

You should use in-place modifications *unless* one or more of the following conditions apply:

- The array should not be altered, as in it's an argument you don't "own"
- The array is *frozen* and cannot be altered

The differences get magnified depending on how many operations you're doing. If you're doing a lot of append operations it might make sense to accumulate those in an append buffer, the add them on all at once like:

```rb
y = [ ] 
z.each do |a|
  # Example with processing
  y << a
end

x = x.concat(y)
```

Though these are highly situational.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your main confusion seems to be that you are confusing variables and values. Variables and values are *fundamentally different* and are fundamentally separate concepts that in *almost all* programming languages *never meet*. A *thing* and a *name* of a thing are *not* the same thing!

In your subject line you write [**bold** emphasis mine]:

> What is gained by modifying a variable in place **vs** reassignment in Ruby?

That doesn't make sense. There is *exactly one way* of modifying a variable in Ruby: assignment. It is impossible to modify a variable in any other way except by assigning to it. Period. [Except via Reflection, but once you allow Reflection, everything goes out the window anyway, so I normally ignore it.]

So, asking about "something **vs.** assignment" doesn't make sense because *there is no* alternative "something" which is not assignment that you could compare assignment to.

Again, in the question body you write:

> Are there significant advantages to mutating a variable (**array, hash, etc**) in place in Ruby?

`Array`s and `Hash`es are *values*, they are *not* variables. (Although `Array` *is* a (constant) variable which *references* a value, namely an instance of the class `Class` that represents the concept of an array.)

It is *very important* not just in Ruby, but in programming in general (and even beyond programming) to understand the difference between a *thing* and a *name* for a thing, or a *box* and the thing *inside* the box. A pair of sneakers is *not* the same thing as the shoe carton it is delivered in, nor is it the same thing as the letters "Nike".

So, let's look at the difference here:

> ```ruby
> original_array = []
> original_array << 'first'
> ```

What is happening in this example?

1. You are creating a new *value* (an object that is an instance of the `Array` class) by using the `Array` literal syntax `[]`.
2. You are creating a new *variable* named `original_array` and binding it to the *value* created in step #1.
3. You are *dereferencing* the *variable* `original_array` (i.e. asking the variable for the *value* it is bound to).
4. You are sending the message `<<` to the *value* that was obtained in step #3.
5. The internal implementation of the method that gets invoked in response to that message *mutates* `self`, i.e. the *value* that was the receiver of the message send in step #4.

[I left out a couple of steps such as creating a `String` value, etc. which are not relevant to the understanding.]

*At no point* did you mutate the *variable* `original_array` (after the initial assignment). At the end of this snippet of code, the variable references the *exact same* value it did at the beginning.

You *did* however mutate the *value* that is referenced by that variable. (Or, more precisely, you told the value to mutate itself.)

Now, let's compare that to the second snippet:

> ```ruby
> original_array = []
> original_array = original_array + ['first']
> ```

And here's how the second example compares [note the first three steps are the same]:

1. You are creating a new *value* (an object that is an instance of the `Array` class) by using the `Array` literal syntax `[]`.
2. You are creating a new *variable* named `original_array` and binding it to the *value* created in step #1.
3. You are *dereferencing* the *variable* `original_array` (i.e. asking the variable for the *value* it is bound to).
4. You are sending the message `+` to the *value* that was obtained in step #3.
5. The internal implementation of the method that gets invoked in response to that message returns *a new, different, separate, distinct value*.
6. You are *rebinding* the *variable* `original_array` to the *new value* created in step #5.

*At no point* did you mutate the *value* created in step #1.

You *did* however mutate the *variable* `original_array`.

So, in some sense, the two snippets are exactly *dual* (in the category-theoretical sense of the term):

1. The *variable* is unchanged, the *value* is *mutated*.
2. The *variable* is *mutated*, the *value* is unchanged.

> Is "immutability" even an appropriate concept with which to describe this?

Neither of the two examples are immutable. Either of them mutates *something*, the first mutates the *value*, the second mutates the *variable*.

An *immutable* version looks like this:

```ruby
original_array = []
new_array = original_array + ['first']
```

Note that *in general* mutating variables and mutating values are equally bad. In fact, values (objects) are made up of their *instance variables*, so mutating instance variables *is* mutating the value (object) they belong to.

The "level of badness" is essentially a question of scope. The more limited the scope is, the less bad it is and the easier it is to understand and control.

In your case, you have a local variable. Local variables have local scope (essentially one method body, one (potentially nested) block or lambda body, one module/class body, or one script body). Hopefully, your methods are small enough that you can track and trace all usages and all mutations of a local variable.

Mutating a value, on the other hand, can have much farther consequences. Some completely separate piece of code in a completely separate part of the galaxy might also use this same object, and if you mutate the object, they will see the mutated version, too. It is much harder to understand this "spooky action at a distance". In essence, mutating a value that is shared by two pieces of code tightly couples these two pieces of code together.

Mutating an instance variable is somewhere in between. Yes, you are changing the state of something that might potentially be visible to multiple other pieces of code. But, *only* the object itself is allowed to mutate its instance variables, nobody else can do it. [Again, ignoring Reflection.] So, presumably, the object mutated its own instance variables because someone *explicitly* told it to, and the object will make sure that all its documented and specified invariants will still hold. Also, hopefully, the fact that the object may mutate itself is clearly documented so that no client gets surprised by this.

We can try and derive some general rules:

- You may mutate yourself (your instance variables) provided that this does not change the externally visible documented behavior.
- You may mutate yourself and change your externally visible documented behavior, provided that the fact that the behavior may change and that this particular method may change the behavior is clearly documented.
- You may mutate an object that you created (more precisely, tell the object to mutate itself) provided you never hand this object out to anybody else.
- You may mutate an object that you created and after you are finished mutating it, give it out to somebody else.
- You *must not* mutate an object that you handed out to somebody else.
- You *must not* mutate an object that was handed to you by somebody else.
- You may mutate local variables, provided the scope is small enough to clearly understand what is happening.
- You *must not* use class variables at all, their scope is confusing and much bigger than you think it is.
- You *must not* mutate global variables.
- You *must not* mutate constants. (Yes, it is allowed by Ruby and will "only" generate a warning, but it is just confusing because programmers expect constants to be … uh … constant.)

This *might* seem restrictive, but consider that there are languages like Haskell, where the rule is simply: You *must not* mutate. Anything. Ever. (In fact, you *can't*, the language doesn't even have the capability to.) And yet, we can build just as powerful systems with Haskell as we can with any other language.